# ListBox ItemTemplate based on parent binding value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, datatemplate

Basically, I am looking to create a custom template for my listitems. One template will use checkboxes, while the other will use radioboxes. This is meant to emulate when multiselect is allowed or not. However, I have tried many different ways, with the most promising being the `DataTemplateSelector`, however I need to create a Dependency Property so that I can pass in the boolean `IsMultiSelect` value. But, I need a `DependencyObject` within the Selector, and the closest I can get is the contentpresenter. I know I can get the parent control based off of that, but that seems like a hack. Is there any way to accomplish what I am looking to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if I understood everything correctly, but this may be helpful:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple">
<!--<ListBox SelectionMode="Single">-->
    <ListBox.Items>
        <TextBlock Text="Test 1" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test 2" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test 3" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test 4" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test 5" />
        <TextBlock Text="Test 6" />
    </ListBox.Items>
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="SingleSelectionModeItemTemplate">
                    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                                                     Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 Content="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="MultiSelectionModeItemTemplate">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,
                                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                                                  Mode=TwoWay}"
                              Content="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="SelectionMode"
                         Value="Single">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SingleSelectionModeItemTemplate}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="SelectionMode"
                         Value="Multiple">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MultiSelectionModeItemTemplate}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Much better than my solution :) Thanks a ton for the simple way. I danced around Style Triggers, but for some reason never actually thought to use the SelectionMode as the trigger as I kept trying my binding. And, I kept focusing on the items in ItemTemplate setting something, rather than setting ItemTemplate itself. Also, RadioButton needs a GroupName to make it single select, but that is more of my implementation detail and not part of the question :)